# How to match files *.R and *Rd with find utility?

Tags: regex, find

I would like to find all files that end with `.c`, `.R`, or `.Rd`. I tried

```
find . -iname "*.[cR]" -print
```

which gives all files that end with `.c` or `.R`. How can I additionally get `.Rd` files as well? I know that `[]` only matches one character, but I couldn't adjust it to provide `.Rd` files as well (tried to work with `|` or option `-regex` etc.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here you go =)

```
find -name "*.c" -o -name "*.R" -o -name "*.Rd"
```

If it's just the 3 extension types that you are looking for, I'd recommend staying away from regex and just using the `-o` (as in "or") operator to compose your search instead.

Comment: This solutions seems to be platform dependent: I have installed a Cygwin UNIX emulator on my Windows PC, and the following find command seem to be working: `find ./ -name "*.exe"` and `find ./ -name "*.dll"` but `find ./ -name "*.exe" -o name "*.dll"` seems not to work.

Answer (score 8):

A suitable use of `-regex` would be:

```
find -regex '.*\.\(R\|Rd\|c\)'
```

If you want to use regular expressions you need to keep in mind that these apply to the whole path, not only to the filename:

```
   -regex pattern
          File  name  matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match
          on the whole path, not a search.  For example, to match  a  file
          named `./fubar3', you can use the regular expression `.*bar.' or
          `.*b.*3', but not `f.*r3'.  The regular  expressions  understood
          by  find  are by default Emacs Regular Expressions, but this can
          be changed with the -regextype option.
```

I agree with sampson-chen's answer, that regexes are probably not the best choice here.

Comment: Example of using regextype: find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.(R|Rd|c)'

Comment: I notice that ^ and $ seem to be implicitly at the start and end. "file.R.foo" does not match even though "$" is not specified at the end.

Comment: Also consider: find . | egrep '\.(R|Rd|c)$'